# How to prevent a gap between two canvas in python

Tags: python, tkinter, pack, tkinter-canvas

This code produces two canvases in a window. However Python does not stick them one to another but places a gap between them. This gap gets even wider when I resize the window.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):

       master.title('Python Canvas Testing')
       master.minsize(width=550, height=450)

       settingscanvas = Canvas(master,bg="yellow")
       settingscanvas.pack(side='top',anchor='nw',expand=True,fill='x')

       datacanvas = Canvas(master,bd=1,bg="green")
       datacanvas.pack(side='top',anchor='nw',expand=True,fill='both')

       for r in xrange(15):
          Label(settingscanvas, text='Label'+str(r+1)).grid()

       Label(datacanvas, text='Label 2').grid()

## create main program window
window = Tk()

## create window container
app = App(window)

mainloop()
```

Is there any option that I miss to stick the two canvases together so that there is no gap?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: mixing `pack` and `grid` is not only possible, but a good practice. The only time you can't do that is with two or more widgets that share a common parent. In this case the widgets have different parents.

Comment: I did not notice they were in different parent widgets, I completely retract my original comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both widgets have `expand` set to `True`,so they each are assigned some of the extra space. If you want only one to get the extra space, set `expand` to `False` for the other one. If you want them both to be given some of the extra space, be sure to set `fill` to include the y direction.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.
Since in my application the first canvas does not change in content I could set it to expand=False and now have my desired behaviour.
I was under the impression that "expand=True" is required for "fill", which it is obviously not.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to make it work with pack. But you can do it with the grid manager. To have expandable widget with grid, you need to set two things. First, the "sticky" parameter allows the widget to fill the space inside his cell in the grid ('ew' fills horizontally, 'nsew' fills in both directions). Second, the weight parameter of the column and/or the row make it expendable if positive.

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
       master.title('Python Canvas Testing')
       master.minsize(width=550, height=450)

       settingscanvas = Canvas(master,bg="yellow")
       settingscanvas.grid(sticky='ew')

       datacanvas = Canvas(master,bd=1,bg="green")
       datacanvas.grid(sticky='nsew')

       master.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
       master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

       for r in range(15):
          Label(settingscanvas, text='Label'+str(r+1)).grid()

       Label(datacanvas, text='Label 2').grid()

## create main program window
window = Tk()

## create window container
app = App(window)

mainloop()
```

Comment: I did not go with your example because for some reason I arrived at "pack" in my application to get all the widgets where they need to be. Nonetheless this solution also fulfills the requirement defined in my example here.